# Sudden Problem in my MainActivity.kt file in SRC for Flutter Project

Tags: flutter

I went to this file to get the Android Package name, but after copying and pasting the name (without editing anything), suddenly I face an error I cannot solve.

I am not sure why this error only occurred when I am halfway through the project when I open this file. How do I resolve this?

I tried to see what Inspector suggested, but it did not help.

[Image of the error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWoa5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Viewing it directly as a [Flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flutter_(software)) project will prompt an error. If you want to view Android without an error message, you should open it according to the following steps, menu *Tools* → *Flutter* → *Open for Editing in Android Studio*.